# SharePoint Foundation 2013 403 forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, 403

So last week, around Thursday I believe, our SharePoint Foundation site quit working.  Turns out the SQL service was turned off for some reason (I was gone).  Yesterday (Monday) I turned the SharePoint SQL service back on; this caused the SharePoint SQL database to be recovered for some reason.  That ran its course, and now no one can access the SharePoint website.

When someone tries to access the site, they simply get a "403 FORBIDDEN".  No prompt for logging in, no nothing.  I've been doing research but have not found anything similar, just the 403 error appearing randomly, when accessing photos, or accessing custom applications.

Some other side notes, the "SQL Server Agent (SHAREPOINT)" is not started in Sql Server Configuration Manager.  Also, the SharePoint application pool account only has "Connect" permissions granted for the SharePoint SQL Database.  Plus, Central Administration is accessable for the admin.

I've tried restarting the IIS site, re-running the SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration program, and checked the permissions for the site's bin folder.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a link that contains a piece of the SP log file:  http://jpst.it/ALf4

One interesting finding in the log:

> Access to this document has been blocked because the SPSite is ReadLocked or set to No Access.

Comment: can you share the sharepoint error log details as well as event logs

Comment: Updated original post.  Has a link to a portion of the SP log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the lock state of the site collection. If it is ReadOnly/NoAccess, first restore to normal mode. You may refer the below command

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "<SiteCollection url>" -LockState "Unlock"
```

For additional details, [reference link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc263238.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Verify is the services of sharpoint is running and see in IIS-application pools the SharePoint pools are running